# Why is my quicksort implementation slow when given a presorted input?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort so I can analyze its runtime on different inputs.  My implementation below runs very poorly on presorted inputs (integers in ascending order).

Given the integers 1-5000, here are the runtimes for my sort:

- Randomly ordered input: 0.052 seconds
- Descending order input: 0.065 seconds
- Ascending order input:  0.209 seconds

Given the integers 1-50000, here are the runtimes for my sort:

- Randomly ordered input: 0.585 seconds
- Descending order input: 1.598 seconds
- Ascending order input:  6.540 seconds

I'm not sure what's causing the long runtime on presorted inputs.

```
int median(vector<int> *input, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (right + left) / 2;
    int temp;

    // This method also orders the selected left, mid, and right values
    if ((*input)[mid] < (*input)[left]) {
        temp = (*input)[mid];
        (*input)[mid] = (*input)[left];
        (*input)[left] = temp;
    }
    if ((*input)[right] < (*input)[left]) {
        temp = (*input)[left];
        (*input)[left] = (*input)[right];
        (*input)[right] = temp;
    }
    if ((*input)[mid] < (*input)[right]) {
        temp = (*input)[mid];
        (*input)[mid] = (*input)[right];
        (*input)[right] = temp;
    }

    temp = (*input)[mid];
    (*input)[mid] = (*input)[right-1];
    (*input)[right-1] = temp;

    return (*input)[right-1];
}

void quickSort2(vector<int> *input, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        // Get pivot (median of 3)
        int pivot = median(input, left, right);
        int temp;

        int i = left, j = right - 1;
        for (; ; ) {
            while ((*input)[++i] < pivot) {}
            while (j > 0 && (*input)[--j] > pivot) {}
            if (i < j) {
                temp = (*input)[i];
                (*input)[i] = (*input)[j];
                (*input)[j] = temp;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        temp = (*input)[i];
        (*input)[i] = (*input)[right - 1];
        (*input)[right - 1] = temp;

        quickSort(input, left, i - 1);
        quickSort(input, i + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to see exactly what it's doing? You could specifically try analysing the relevant section of the array (before and after the median call) and the pivot at each step.

Comment: why is i and j global variables

Comment: Because you're using the rightmost element as a pivot and when this is done in a sorted list this results in chronically bad pivot selection.  This has been covered at length: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-does-the-worst-case-of-quicksort-occur/

Comment: Yep, I just commented on his answer to add the comment info. Quick sort is quick -- just not in the worst case choice of pivots `:)`

Comment: Why are you passing **pointers** to vectors instead of using references? Are you allowed to use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

Comment: That's why nobody uses quicksort without a randomized pivot. However, all that is covered by any better textbook.

Comment: As a side note, I would not change the order of elements in the median selection. This is a side-effect that is certainly not clearly expressed by the name of the method, which sounds like a pure 'get' method.

Comment: @Bob__ Passing by pointer is just what I'm used to.  After researching, it does look like passing by reference would make my code a bit cleaner (and easier to write, with less dereferencing all over the place).  Swap would help with clarity, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using the rightmost element as a pivot and when this is done in a sorted list this results in chronically bad pivot selection. This has been covered at length: geeksforgeeks.org/when-does-the-worst-case-of-quicksort-occur

Try changing your third conditional:

```
if ((*input)[mid] < (*input)[right]) {
```

to

```
if ((*input)[right] < (*input)[mid]) {
```

Otherwsie, the swap will put the rightmost (largest) element into [mid] and then you (eventually) return it as output.

*Edited for clarity*

Comment: Add your comment information to your answer. We like answers to be complete. You are correct on the selection of the pivot having the extreme effect on sort time. Using the rightmost pivot is the worst-case for sorted input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you.

Comment: That was definitely the issue, thanks.  I had made the same mistake in the right/left check, and simply forgot to fix the mid/right check, as well.  All that effort to pick a median value and I ended up picking the rightmost value as a pivot. Oops.  The runtime is now down to 0.030, 0.028, 0.014 seconds and 0.374, 0.330, 0.185 seconds for 5000 and 50000 inputs, respectively.